# rosserial_arduino and Arduino IDE 1.0 rc2

Tags: ros, arduino, ide, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a newbie to ROS, rosserial and Arduino.  Nonetheless, I'm trying my hand at doing some development.  When I tried to compile the rosserial_arduino example for HelloWorld using the Arduino IDE (1.0 rc2), it wouldn't compile as a result of the renaming of "Wprogram.h" to "Arduino.h".  I solved the problem by editing ArduinoHardware.h to replace:

```
#include <Wprogram.h>
```

with:

```
#if ARDUINO>=100
#include <Arduino.h> // Arduino 1.0
#else
#include <Wprogram.h> // Arduino 0022
#endif
```

Hopefully (1) this is the preferred solution and (2) it gets propagated into the rosserial package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11789/rosserial_arduino-and-arduino-ide-1.0-rc2/) by [mcsmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/1313/mcsmith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-11-03

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AzureViolin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1837/azureviolin/) on 2012-03-20**:
This is cool, man. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the patch -- in the future, feel free to file a ticket on our Kforge Trac: https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/trac

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on 2012-08-16**:
Is there a plan to push this fix out in the debs? Still seems to be broken in ros-fuerte-rosserial.